# CUDA - Bus Error

Tags: opencv, cuda

I have been working with CUDA for a while now and started to have bus errors reported on the first attempt to malloc any data to the GPU after working for a short period of time.  The only way that i have found to fix this is to restart the machine.

The memory should be cleared up automatically but it does not seem to happen if the application crashes before reaching all of the cudaFree calls.

Has anybody else had this problem or know how to force the card memory to clear?  I am using ubuntu 10 x64 with a 480Fermi.

should also add: using CUDA with openCV for real time image processing

Answer (score 1):

self solve

the problem was with one of the cuda malloc calls

Comment: Why don't you give some details, so that future people who find your question can see what mistake you made and how to fix it? Maybe they made the same mistake. (note: this isn't a forum. You should only post actual answers here as an answer, even for your own question!)

Comment: Very difficult to say in this particular case, but in some cases the bus error comes because of not synchronizing the host (using cudaDeviceSynchronize()) after using cudaMallocManaged call.